# Vertical Text alignment for RichEditBox in uwp

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

How to vertically align the text in the [RichEditBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox?view=winrt-22621) in uwp, I've read the whole documentation but could not found how to achieve that.

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        RichEditBox box1;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            box1 = new RichEditBox()
            {
                Width = 500,
                Height = 500,
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)
            };
            box1.Document.SetText(0, "asdfghjklkjhgfdsgffffffffffff\nzAsdfghjk\nlkjhgfdsasdfgh\nkjhgfdfghjkl\nlkjhgfdghjk");
            box1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            Content = box1;
        }
}
```

As shown in the image I was able to align the text horizontally but not able to align the text vertically.
[image]

Below is the example how in excel sheet they achieved the vertical align and horizontal align both
[image]

Comment: What do you mean about `vertically align`? It's better to share more information about the expected behavior you want to get like image of wanted behavior.

Comment: Could you please share more information about the expected behavior you want to get like image? What is the `vertically align` effect looks like ?

Comment: You want to put text in the center of the `RichEditBox`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is built-in API that could directly change the VerticalAlignment of the text. The `TextAlignment` property could only change the `HorizontalAlignment`.

You have to change the default style of the [RichEditBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox?view=winrt-22621) to get what you want.

1. Create a default style of the `RichEditBox`
2. Find a `ScrollViewer` object which named **ContentElement** inside the style. It's the place where text are placed.
3. Set the `VerticalAlignment` property of the **ContentElement** to `Center` and the text will be placed in the center Vertically.

The following XAML style is what I used for test:

```
        <Style x:Key="RichEditBoxStyle1" TargetType="RichEditBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentLinkForegroundColor" Value="{ThemeResource ContentLinkForegroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentLinkBackgroundColor" Value="{ThemeResource ContentLinkBackgroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RichEditBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="{ThemeResource RichEditBoxTopHeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"  VerticalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsTabStop="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Description}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}" Grid.Row="2" x:Load="False"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The result looks like:

[image]